# WKHTMLTOPDF php wrapper

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I have been using Mike Haertl PHP wrapper for WKHTMLTOPDF without problem, but felt it best to install the latest version, however i am struggling with Composer and where the files should be stored.

Currently i have installed Composer and the Wrapper and they are sitting in my servers root/vendor, along with the autoload.php. When i try and include the autoload.php in my script it won't allow me access to it. Not sure that i should have this in root at all!

```
require('/root/vendor/autoload.php');
use mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf;
```

Sorry but I'm a novice when it comes to server installations!

Error message from PHP: 
    pageWarning: require(/root/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in etc.....

I have checked the permissions which allow read write etc. and the i changed the owner from root to the regular owner of the server.

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: Hi Mario, i have added the php return message to the original message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already noted, this touches the area of server administration.  It's a complicated topic, and if your page is going to be accessible from the internet, I'd advice to find some help to set things up.

You rightfully noted that it seems strange to put code into the `/root` directory.  That folder is the superuser's home directory and should only contain his/her data.  Code, on the other hand, is supposed to be read by the webserver.  The "correct" place to put code varies between linux distributions.  Usual places are `/var/www/your-project` or `/srv/www/code-goes-here`.

I'm guessing that you are following a tutorial which told you to put the code into your root directory?  They didn't mean the actual `/root` or even `/` paths, put the main folder, in which your web application resides.  Root is often a relative term as it refers to the top-most directory of an entity – the webapp in this case.

Try moving the library to a different folder.  You also might want to pick up a short tutorial about composer, understanding how it works can be quite helpful in situations like these.

Comment: Thanks for your help, moved to the /var/ folder and worked perfectly!